# why cannot read property 'top' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with sticky navbar fixed top and structure of sticky navbar and my sticky navbar structure is

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(".b").offset().top + $(".b").height() && $("input").val() == "") {
      $(".sticky").show();
    } else {
      $(".sticky").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 100px 0;
}
.a:after {
  content: "A";
  font-size: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
.b:after {
  content: "B";
  font-size: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
.c:after {
  content: "C";
  font-size: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
ul.sticky {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
ul.sticky:after,
ul.sticky:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
ul.sticky li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
ul.sticky li a:hover {
  background: #999;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sticky">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Download</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Forums</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/yedincifirat/pen/ALBJXG)

and my question is if I'm not putting my `.sticky` element another pages javascript notifier give me this error and I am not gonna put my `.sticky` element every page  what do I have to do ?

[image]

[click to see real demo](https://apps.anitur.com.tr/anitur/otel-listeleme.html)

[click to see getting error](https://apps.anitur.com.tr/anitur/anasayfa.html)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: and do I have to do like this ? var myElem = $(".b").offset ?

Comment: @fortherest: I've taken your code blocks and put them in a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) in your question. The code here in the question does not produce the error you describe. Please use Stack Snippets, not CodePen, to ensure that the code with the problem is actually here on-site. (Including a CodePen link *as well* is okay, but the chief thing is to ensure that the question itself is self-contained.)

Comment: @DavidJawphan: [No, it shouldn't.](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) And in any case, the OP is using the `ready` shortcut, so it will work either way.

Comment: T.J Crowder let me explain
I got .sticky element and js codes if I'm not putting my sticky element I'm getting js error and my js files is same in every project

Comment: @fortherest: Just update the question to demonstrate the problem in the snippet, and tell us how to make it happen (what we need to do after running the snippet to see the error).

Comment: I will add new demo link to see issue

Comment: @fortherest: *"I will add new demo link to see issue"* ***No.*** Update **the question's code in the snippet** to demonstrate the issue, and tell us how to run that code **in the question** to see the error. Questions must be self-contained.

Comment: Fundamentally, the only reason `offset` will return `undefined` is if you call it on an empty jQuery set (no matching elements). So that's the problem. The only question is why. Your markup above has a `.b` element, so it won't do that. Does something remove that element at some stage? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: I edited my qestion and added real demo

Comment: @fortherest: For the fourth time: Put the code, markup, CSS that demonstrate the problem **in the question**, not just linked. Put the instructions for how to run the snippet to see the problem in the question.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder already hinted, the issue is simply that the element you are looking for [is not present in the DOM](http://imgur.com/a/65xij). He is also right in that you should not link to off-site resources. First do your best to narrow down the error to a minimal test case, then post that test case on SO. This saves us time debugging and ensures you get a fast reply.

Comment: sorry my english is not enough to understand very well.my codepen demo is same my real demo nothing change.and yes problem is probably offset return undefined but if I remove my .sticky structure on html no error js give me anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error beacause jQuery did not find the element `.hotel-search-box` in your website.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!$(".hotel-search-box").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height() && $(".oda-giris-cikis").val() == ""){
          $(".sticky-checkin").show();
      }else{
          $(".sticky-checkin").hide();
      }
  });
});
```

To fix your probleme add a `.hotel-search-box` element in your page where you want to show your sticky menu.

Comment: yes the problem was this but how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: To fix your probleme add a .hotel-search-box element in your page where you want to show your sticky menu.

Comment: I just want to add one page but if I'm not putting another page I'm getting this error

Comment: Ok, then we should check if the element exist first ;), i will edit my post

Comment: thanks @SofieneDjebali T.J Crowder I couldn't explain because I have no enough english to explain as I want sorry about that otherwise my question was how to do that logically and I understand by the Sofiende Djebali

Comment: @fortherest: No, it's not a language problem. You can clearly understand enough English to know what "Put the actual code in the question" means.